# How to register a local git package in Bower?

Tags: javascript, git, package, bower, bower-register

How can I register a local git package in bower?

My current component.json is as follows

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.8.0",
    "twitter/bootstrap": "2.1.1"
  }
}
```

However I also would like to add a package I have created at `C:/mypackage` which is a git repository with versions tagged.
When I do `bower install --save C:/mypackage` it properly adds it to project but it doesn't add it to my component.json.

I am trying `bower register mypackage C:/mypackage` but it keeps giving me

```
bower error Incorrect format
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 71):

### Option 1: Public Bower registration

Bower is built mostly to share public (client-side) code in a "non-opinionated" manner. The primary use case, then, is to have a publicly accessible repository (on GitHub) that is `register`d with a name and git repository url. I just did this myself:

```
bower register linksoup git://github.com/automatonic/linksoup
```

This is just telling the bower server that when you `install linksoup` to go and grab the code at the `git://github.com/automatonic/linksoup` repository, and put it in the local project's `component` directory.

If this is what you want to do, then just set up a repository on github/etc., push your code there, and then `register` with the resulting repository info.

### Option 2: Private dependency

There are many reasons not to post your code at a publicly accessible repository. It may not be open source, etc. if your `mypackage` code is not meant to be public, then you should probably not be `register`ing it on the public bower server... Further, even if you could `register` a local directory, it would only work on your machine...which defeats the purpose of sharing the code via bower.

If you just want to have bower manage a local, private dependency, then I am going to riff off of [blockhead's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13807081/8668) solution:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.8.0",
    "twitter/bootstrap": "2.1.1",
    "mypackage": "file:///path/to/mypackage/.git"
  }
}
```

This is just saying that `myproject` needs `mypackage`, and to use git clone to retrieve it. My guess is that this can use anything git can understand (including local repositories). But you should note that this may run into problems for anyone else working on this code that cannot access your local path.

### Best Guess

It looks to me as if you may have assumed that `bower register` was a local operation (telling bower how to find a dependency via some sort of local registry). As far as I can tell, this is only a remote and public registration, which is why this is unsupported.

You may also be looking for a way to do something like a [link operation with npm](https://npmjs.org/doc/link.html). That is, work on a dependency module without always having your dev cycle include a publish.

A little detail about how many people are involved and what you were trying to accomplish would facilitate a more targeted answer.

Comment: I had to use a private git repository as well, but I wanted to do it from a shared network folder location. After some playing around I got it to work using this format: `"file:////networkdomain.com/path/to/mypackage/.git"` (emphasis on the 4 slashes after `file:` instead of 3)

Answer (score 53):

You can add any git repository as follows:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.8.0",
    "twitter/bootstrap": "2.1.1",
    "myrepo":"git://myrepo.com/myrepo"
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember to specify the branch: "myrepo":"git://myrepo.com/myrepo#branch"

Comment: @FrederikWordenskjold - it will default to the master branch, but an awesome comment none-the-less! I upvoted ya, just thought i would add this small detail.

Comment: The question clearly says local git package and still this answer gets 33 upvotes?

Comment: The point is, you can do any git repository. Doesn't matter if its remote or local. I was just showing that its possible.

Comment: Which is appreciated -- I came here to find out how to do this with a remote repository, not a local one.

Answer (score 33):

You can use `bower link`:

> The link functionality allows developers to easily test their packages.
>   Linking is a two-step process.
>
> Using `bower link` in a project folder will create a global link.
>   Then, in some other package, `bower link <pkg>` will create a link in the components folder
>   pointing to the previously created link.
>
> This allows to easily test a package because changes will be reflected immediately.
>   Please note that bower will not fetch the linked package dependencies.
>
> Bower will overwrite the link when installing/updating.

Comment: You can use symlinks manually without going through bower. This will work for others as well, but I am not sure about Windows devs. This is the only way I found that can be shared with other devs.

Comment: @xixixao bower linking is done in two step, so if you move your package you just need to update bower link, but if you link directly then if you move your package you need to update all dependent packages manually.

Answer (score 24):

The big idea with [`bower`](https://github.com/bower/bower) is to easily share your projects' dependencies. So **using local repo should be limited to testing**.

Once you understand that, you should know that it is not –strictly– necessary to `register` your package in order to use it as a dependency.

This is due to the fact that bower depencency can specify either a *version*, a *folder* or a *package*. So **you can use local repository**.

### Define as bower package

First you will need to [define your dependency as a bower package](https://github.com/bower/bower#defining-a-package):

```bsh
# create the bower package
cd /path/to/you-need-me
bower init
# answer questions…
```

### Add as project dependency

Then in your main project, the one that need the `you-need-me` dependency, edit `bower.json` file to add (or expand):

```
  "dependencies": {
    …
    "you-need-me":  "file:///path/to/you-need-me/.git/"
    "you-need-me-windows":  "C:/path/to/you-need-me-windows/.git/"
  }
```

So you don't give a version, but an local `git` endpoint, i.e. **the subdirectory `.git/`**.

### Install dependency

In the man project install bower dependencies with:

```
cd /path/to/main-project/
bower install
```

#### Failure

```
bower you-need-me#*              ENOTFOUND Package /path/to/you-need-me/ not found
```

Check again your path and that you point to the `.git/` directory of your dependency.

#### Success

You should get something like:

```
bower you-need-me#*             not-cached file:///path/to/you-need-me/.git/#*
bower you-need-me#*                resolve file:///path/to/you-need-me/.git/#*
bower you-need-me#*               checkout master
bower you-need-me#*               resolved file:///path/to/you-need-me/.git/#b18c753c6f
bower you-need-me#*                install you-need-me#b18c753c6f
```

Write a blog entry about that: [Testing bower.json locally before registering package](http://blog.edouard-lopez.com/testing-bower-dot-json-locally-before-registering-package/).

Comment: The .git part of file:///path/to/you-need-me/.git/ wasn't obvious, thanks for that.

Comment: Ye and not referring to the actual repo doesn't work using file:// protocol... bower just hangs...