# Best way to keep files that are used in multiple projects in sync?

Tags: javascript

I have a few files called `"helpers.scss"`, `"helpers.js"` and `"consolerules.js"` that I use in every one of my projects. When I'm working on a project I'm modifying one of the files, for example I will add a function for replacing all strings within a strings into `"helpers.js"` but then when I open my other project I don't have that function.

Or I will add a helper css class in `helpers.scss` in the other project and I don't have it in the other projects.

What is the best way so I can always keep them in sync when I edit them in one of the projects? I was thinking of bower, gists, git, dropbox, google drive or something like that ...

Comment: Create a folder called "Shared" and reference all your projects to that folder. You don't mention which technology you're using other than javascript. So on a server environment, you can have a directory outside all of your root domains that all those domains have access to. Then you update only that 1 directory

Comment: I'd say this depends on the version control system you are using - and you are using one already, right? If not, decide which one to use and adopt the best practice (branching, etc.) of this system.

Comment: You have to move these files in a separate project which will be a CDN for your projects

Comment: You could have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114781/bower-registering-local-git-package

Comment: This question might better be asked at [Programmers.SE]

Answer (score 2):

I used two ways to handle these:

**Get a CDN like server**

Have a single version of those files and place them on a server. For example you could have URLs such as:

```
https://cdn.example.com/css/helpers.css
https://cdn.example.com/js/helpers.js
```

If you want to support versions (maybe you should?), you can add that to the filename:

```
https://cdn.example.com/css/helpers-1.3.css
https://cdn.example.com/js/helpers-1.2.js
```

Or to the path if you view all your files as having one common version:

```
https://cdn.example.com/1.2/css/helpers.css
https://cdn.example.com/1.2/js/helpers.js
```

Versioning is useful if you want to test a website with the newest version before using that version on your live site.

This is most certainly the easiest way if you can implement it that way. Now all your other websites will use those URLs instead of local versions of the files:

```html
<link type="text/stylesheet" href="https://cdn.example.com/1.2/css/helpers.css"/>
```

**Pull those files at build time**

Depending on how you organize your websites (it is really not clear from your questions) and assuming you have folders on your machine with the original source, you can bring in those files as required with a script that you run before you upload your sites.

In my case, I like to do that in three steps:

1. I write the files
2. I copy the files to a .../build/... folder
3. I send the .../build/... folder to my test or production server

One reason for this is to generate a build folder that includes exactly what you want, verify it, then send it to your server. That verification happens only when you write your script. Once done, it should not require any additional work.

So... one reason to get such a script is that I can compile my files. For example, if you write PHP code, the servers only need the most compressed version of your code (unless you are debugging and need to find line numbers...) The script that generate the build folder could do:

```sh
for p in php/*.php
do
    php -w $p build/$p
done
```

Now your PHP code on your server may be something like 20% smaller.

Similarly, you could copy your `helper.css` file as in:

```sh
cp ../helper-project/css/helper.css build/public_html/css/.
```

This copies the helpers.css file to your build folder. Since it grabs that file from your **unique** `../helper-project` folder, you will always end up with the latest.

And instead of a simple `cp` command, you could also minimize that file at the same time:

```
cleancss --remove-empty ../helper-project/css/helper.css > build/public_html/css/.
```

The only problem here is that if you make changes to the helper-project, it won't automatically update all the projects. You still have to do in each project and run the script(s) that generate the build folder and copy that to your servers. Yet, I find that to be a practical way of doing things because that way I know when I do the update and I can test the resulting website(s) before going to production and once I update a production site, I can verify that it's still all working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with git (or any modern VCS); I assume you are using some sort of VCS for your code.
If you have a project being managed in git, you can even add multiple remotes, such that you can pull in code from multiple sources.

If you are using a VCS like git, then it is just a matter of doing a `git pull <remote ref> <branch ref>` whenever you want to sync up.

Otherwise, the comments to your question offer some alternatives.