# Clone repo using bower

Tags: git, bower, bower-install

When I run bower install `package name` or `git url` then it installs the package in the specified directory - but the package does not contain the .git directory - is there a way for bower to clone the entire repo (from a remote source, not using a pre-cloned repo on my disk) such that I could then just cd into the directory and make a change if required during the packages development? It seems npm is capable of this by just installing from a repo.

I know I could potentially just run `bower link` to symlink a local copy of the cloned repo elsewhere - or even cd into the package dir and clone the repo inside this but I thought maybe it was possible via config?

Comment: You can set the git repository URL to a local folder on your computer in your bower.json file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bower registering local git package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114781/bower-registering-local-git-package)

Comment: I could - but what I mean is by running `bower install link to package` - inside my component dir would be the installed package - but its folder would contain the git repo and not just the source code. Such that I could make a change there and commit back to the repo.

Comment: If the bower package source is installed in your git repo directory and you bower install from that directory you'll come close to what you want.