# What is the best practice for modifying a bower component JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bower

I wanted to ask a general question regarding programing technique.
In case I have downloaded a bower component and i have to (yes, have to, can do nothing but that) modify the js file in order it to work for my business use, what is the proper way to do that modification?

I wouldn't like to fork it from github since it's not relevant for all other people in the world.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bower registering local git package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114781/bower-registering-local-git-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make some changes and working on a detached bower component, the best solution would be to move the bower component outside of the bower_components folder; remove that from inside your bower.json dependencies and continue working on your local folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.
That's what i thought, but did not know if there is a better way or anything else i did not think of.
Thanks again.

Comment: That's the best way. When you "remove" the component from inside the bower folder and from the bower.json you're not going to sync the code in that folder any more so, technically that part of the code becomes part of your local application and there is no relation with bower any more.